# Prove that $ \mathbb{P}\left(Y_{n}\geq0\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\geq0\right) $

Tags: probability

Let $ \left(X_{n}\right)_{n} $ be a sequence of random variables, $X$ a random variable and $ Z $ a random variable, such that for any $ n $ we have $ |X_{n}|\leq Z  $, and $ X_{n}\overset{a.s}{\longrightarrow}X $. Now define $ Y_{n}=2Z-|X-X_{n}| $.

Is it true that all the given details that I wrote here is enough to conclude that $ \mathbb{P}\left(Y_{n}\geq0\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z\geq0\right)=1 $ ?

If so, I'll be glad if someone can show how to prove it. Thanks in advance

Comment: from the almost sure convergence it should follow that also $|X|\leq Z$ almost surely, does that help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's evident that $Z \ge 0$ almost sure because $Z \ge |X_1| \ge 0$. So,   $P(Z \ge 0) = 1$

Besides, we have
\begin{align}
Z \ge |X_1| &\iff  -Z<X_n<Z 
\end{align}

Hence, $-Z<\lim X_n<Z $ or $-Z<X<Z$ or $$|X| \le Z$$
Now we have
$$Y_n = 2Z-|X-X_n| \ge 2Z-(|X|+|X_n|) \ge 0$$

We can conclude that  $P(Y_n \ge 0) = 1$.